Event based action in Outlook web addin stops working when Admin deployed
I'm developing an Outlook web  addin for Microsoft 365 accounts following Microsoft documents that consists of manifest.xml,  webpack.config.js etc.  It has:

a button we can click to display a taskpane

an Event based action to display a sentence in infobar automatically triggered by "OnMessageCompose"


When I sideload by running npm on localhost, both the button and  that Event based action to show infobar work well, on both Outlook application and  Outlook on web.
When Admin deployed (we just replaced localhost by remote url in manifest.xml), the button still work well.
But for that Event based action:

now in Outlook application, upon composing an email, infobar is not displayed, and it displays a taskpane saying:


ADD_IN ERROR
We can't start this add-in because it isn't set up properly.


in Outlook on web, infobar is not displayed, and it shows no error.

Since the addin is now hosted remotely, I believe we can not debug in VS Code any more.
I tried to debug in Outlook on web (chrome) by pressing F12.  Under  Network tab it does show it successfully downloaded that javascript file  successfully.  However under the Source tab it does not show that  javascript file at all.  Under the domain hosting this addin it only  showed the assets/ folder.  So I don't know how to debug now.
What is the problem?  And how I should debug?
Thanks.

Are you using HTTP anywhere? I've had issues w/ HTTPS/SSL that didn't appear until I tested under production.

Load your task pane outside  of office (in Edge) and try and debug that way, it can help to remove "office" from the debugging.
